# Meteor android build failed - Example app working but main app throwing err-

Tags: android, meteor

**Status**: Didn't found a solution. I am editing my steps what i try at the end of question.

**This is working** (Creating example app, and running on android):

```
meteor create meteor-example
```

.. blah blah ..

```
meteor run android
```

**But my main project isn't** working. Here is the verbose code

```
:processDebugManifest
 FAILEDting app on Android Emulator          \                      

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/sea/Android/Sdk/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.557 secs
Error code 1 for command: /home/sea/allinone/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/sea/allinone/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/build.gradle,-PcdvBuildArch=x86,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true undefined
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:         

   While running Cordova app for platform Android with options --emulator:
   Error: Command failed:                     
   /home/sea/allinone/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/run
   --emulator

   at ChildProcess.exitCallback (/tools/utils/processes.js:151:23)
   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)

/home/sea/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.3_1.qc654++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/isopackets/cordova-support/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:165
      throw error;
            ^
ExitWithCode:1
```

I see the error at first line, now.

> ```
> :processDebugManifest
>      FAILEDting app on Android Emulator          \
> ```

Should i create a mobileconfig.js for it? I don't know how to use mobileconfig, but if necessary i'll search for it.

---

**My Debugging Survey**:

**1)** Fail message was: `:processDebugManifestFAILEDting app on Android Emulator`. I think i should edit my cordova's androidManifest in `.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android`. To inspect what is wrong, opened two manifest file (ExampleApp's manifest,MainApp's manifest). Everything looks same. *Changed uses-sdk minSdkVersion 14 to 21*, computer frozen, usb mouse working with delay. Restarted the computer. Trying again with `meteor run android-device --verbose`

Final: Throwed same error.

I think its related with androidManifest file.

Comment: To run an emulated device you need to have Android Studio installed. You may want to try running it on android-device if you can plug one in via USB, as the emulator is pretty slow (as suggested in the guide/docs).

Comment: @AnthonyAstige In example project folder, everything is ok, app building, emulator opening the example app, everything is fine. But in my main project folder throwing error when building app. I guess problem isn't related the Android Studio. Btw, thanks for suggestion, i'll try it.